# How would I display a message saying your time is up then terminate the program

Tags: c#, timer

I have created a timer for 30 seconds that i'll use per method. How would I display a message long enough for them to read it then terminate the program?

```
namespace Calculator{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);

            Console.WriteLine("INSTRUCTIONS - You have 30 seconds to answer each question correctly, once you get the question right the next question will appear," +
            "if you get a question wrong the console will display INCORRECT and you will have until the end of the 30 seconds to answer it correctly.");
        //These are the instructions
        timer.Start();
        q1();
        timer.Stop();
        }

        static string q1() //Return type is a string as a string prompting the user will ask them to try again
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1+1"); //This is the question
            int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());// Can't apply int to a readline, so convert the useres input to an int so you can apply an int variable
            if (answer == 2) //If the users input is equal to 2 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct");//Tells the user that they are correct
            }
            return "Incorrect, try again";//Promts the user to trya again

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, a common approach to show the console after the program execution is done, is to wait for a user input using `Console.ReadLine()` for example as the last line of code of your Main method.

Comment: You are going to need to use a timer event.

Comment: @xdtTransform It reads the user input in the q1 method `int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
Console.ReadLine();
```

The console will wait till any key is pressed to continue (or exit the program if it's the last thing)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{

    static ThreadStart ThreadStart = new ThreadStart(Counter);
    static Thread Thread = new Thread(ThreadStart)
    {
        Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest
    };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("INSTRUCTIONS - You have 30 seconds to answer each question correctly, once you get the question right the next question will appear," +
        "if you get a question wrong the console will display INCORRECT and you will have until the end of the 30 seconds to answer it correctly.");
        //These are the instructions



        Thread.Start();

        q1();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    static void Counter()
    {
        if(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < 30000)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Counter();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Too late");

            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

    }

    static void q1() //Return type is a string as a string prompting the user will ask them to try again
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1+1"); //This is the question
        int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());// Can't apply int to a readline, so convert the useres input to an int so you can apply an int variable

        if (answer == 2) //If the users input is equal to 2 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct");//Tells the user that they are correct
            Thread.Abort();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Try again");
            q1();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup that works great thanks, just one more thing though, how would I stop it if the method is correct, as i'd be creating more methods similar to q1() and i'd like the timer to start again when i call the next method

Comment: You gonna have to put thread instance like class field, in order to make it visible in your methods like q1, and use method thread.Abort() in case if was given correct answer. Just eddited code by your question.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("INSTRUCTIONS - You have 30 seconds to answer each question correctly, once you get the question right the next question will appear," +
        "if you get a question wrong the console will display INCORRECT and you will have until the end of the 30 seconds to answer it correctly.");
        //These are the instructions

        q1();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    static void q1() //Return type is a string as a string prompting the user will ask them to try again
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1+1"); //This is the question
        int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());// Can't apply int to a readline, so convert the useres input to an int so you can apply an int variable

        if (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds > 30000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It took you too much time");
        }
        if (answer == 2) //If the users input is equal to 2 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct");//Tells the user that they are correct
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Try again");
            q1();
        }
    }
}
```

You also did not need any return in your method, u haven`t used it anywhere.

Comment: But this would only display that message once the user has actually inputted something into the console, what i meant was it should siplay that as soon as the timer ends